# need to do aop with async while avoiding race conditions

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, aop, aspectj

In order to audit progress of a business logic,been using Spring AspectJ AOP `@Before` , `@AfterReturning` , `@AfterThrowing` advices. But this runs by default on same thread as business logic which is causing delay in business logic. So instead added an `@Async` annotation in each AOP advice. But this leads to too many thread creation for example, for each step a thread gets created like ON_RECEIVE_ADVICE, ON_ENQUEUE_ADVICE , ON_IN_PROGRESS_ADVICE, ON_COMPLETE_ADVICE, ON_FAIL_ADVICE. This further leads to race conditions since ON_RECEIVE_ADVICE might be still inserting record in database, that has to be updated by rest of advices - but on not finding any such record say in ON_ENQUEUE_ADVICE, it re-inserts and there are now duplicates in DB. Database in this case lacks Unique key constraints and has highest READ_COMMITTED transactional isolation.

```
@Before(value = "execution(* com....")
@Async
public void auditStep1(final Dto Dto)
{
    //persist to DB (lack UQ / and has highest READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation )
}

@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com....")
@Async
public void auditStep2(final Dto Dto)
{
    //persist to DB (lack UQ / and has highest READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation )
}

@AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* com....")
@Async
public void auditStep3(final Dto Dto)
{
    //persist to DB (lack UQ / and has highest READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation )
}
```

So mainly these are constraints :

1. Aop/Audit should happen on separate thread from business logic, but not necessarily a thread per advice. Infact even if it happens sequentially but on just another thread it should be fine, so can we share thread between advices using `@Async` annotations

In this case, 3 thread get created and there is race condition as step2 may begin while step1 is doing. `@Transactional` - wont span threads as well I guess and would not be of much help here once need to synchronize between step 1 audit and step 2 audit

Comment: You do not explain what ON_RECEIVE_ADVICE, ON_ENQUEUE_ADVICE etc. are. I can just speculate that these are events reflecting steps in your business process which you want to write to your audit log table. I also do not understand what "too many thread creation for ex" means, it is not English. Does "for ex" mean "for example" maybe or is "ex" just a typo and supposed to mean something else?

Comment: Generally, I do not like the idea to run advices asynchronously, especially around advices. In your case they are only before/after type advices, i.e. they do not influence the behaviour or return values of executed methods, so it should be okay. But if you have race conditions, you need to synchronise on something or use a buffer queue for the messages you want to be written to the database. Of course this is no guarantee that event A is written before event B because in theory B's thread could be faster than A's. But it should be okay for the most part.

Comment: @kriegaex, those advice are  bunch of other Before, AfterReturning , i just have put 3 in example but there are 10. And with Async on top of those methods alongside Before annotations , it goes to the point that there are as many threads as advices. Corrected some other things as well in question. Was looking if there is a way to run bunch of advice like in example as one thread but separate from business logic thread (pointcuts)

Comment: Yes, of course, but - me not being a Spring user, I am not 100% sure - I would guess that there is no way to solve this by configuration only. Why don't you do it yourself, using one thread or small thread pool per advice or aspect? You will need to do some manual bookkeeping, but then you can design it just the way you dream it up. Besides, if your whole application would become significantly slower just because you execute the advices in the same thread as it was designed, then maybe something is wrong with your aspect code. How can the audit code be slower than the actual processing?